# unable to use rsync into a usb drive

Tags: usb, mount, rsync

I have this rsync command:
`rsync -auv -delete /home/user/mc-server-files /home/user/sandisk-usb/mc-server-files >> /home/user/mylogs/school-server-backup.log 2>&1`

I also have it in crontab. When I try to run it manually, it doesn't work. The log file gives me a lot of `Permission denied (13)` I think this is because of the usb drive permissions:

```
Output of ls -l
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root   32768 Aug  2 16:09 sandisk-usb
Output of dF -Th
/dev/sdb1      exfat   29G  320K   29G   1% /home/user/sandisk-usb
Drive mounted with:
mount /dev/sdb1 /home/user/sandisk-usb
```

My user is in the sudo group, but not the root group. I am also unable to change the permissions with `sudo chmod g=rw /home/user/sandisk-usb/mc-server-files`. The command doesn't say anything after running and keeps permissions the same.

Comment: How is it mounted? `mount | grep "/dev/sdb"` will tell. Read `man mount`, there is a section on mounting ExFAT volumes. FAT and NTFS format volumes don't support Linux file ownership or permissions. Can you backup your data and format it as `ext4`. **Warning** No data survives a format. **Warning** `ext4` is incompatible with Windows.

Comment: `rsync` is complaining that it cannot read the files you have told it to back up. In the terminal, you'll have to `sudo rsync ...`. To get your command to work via `crontab`, you'll have to set up passwordless `sudo` access to the `rsync` command. Read `man sudo sudoers` to learn how. Wrap your `sudo rsync ...` command in a `#!/bin/bash` script for easier control, and use the full path for `rsync`

Comment: The solution for me was to umount the drive, then mount it again with ``sudo mount -o uid=1000 /dev/sdb1 /home/user/sandisk-usb``. When I mounted it before I did not specify a user or group like this, so I guess it defaulted to root.